# How can I rename all files in a folder as page001.jpg, page002.jpg, page003.jpg, etc. sorted by their former filenames on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, filenames

I have 50 JPG files in a folder:

- alice.jpg
- bob.jpg
- bobby.jpg
- etc.

How can I rename the files as:

- page001.jpg
- page002.jpg
- page003.jpg
- etc.

sorted by their former filenames on Windows 10? (ascending lexicographic order)

The built-in batch rename in Windows 10 add parentheses and doesn't pad zeroes:

- page (1)
- page (2)
- page (3)
- etc.

Comment: Have you tried [PowerToys](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys)?

Comment: @Ramhound thanks, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/powertoys/powerrename looks promising indeed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Powershell. Use the code below. Change the path on the first line of code.

```ps
cd "c:\path\to\your\files"
#counter for file numbering
$counter = 0    
#List the files, sort them and loop through each file
Gci *.* | Sort | ForEach { 
    $counter = $counter + 1; 
    if($counter -lt 10){
    #Concatenate 00 to the page number if it is less than 10
        $filenumber = "00" + $counter 
        }
    elseif($counter -lt 100){
    #Concatenate 0 to the page number if it is less than 10
        $filenumber = "0" + $counter
        }
    else{
    #if the counter is greater or equal to 100, set filenumber equals to counter
        $filenumber = $counter
        }; 
    #Create the new file name
    $newfilename = -Join("page",$filenumber,$_.Extension); 
    #Rename the file
    Rename-Item $_.name $newfilename
}
```